# Weird R behavior when simulating LLN for standard deviations

Tags: r

I am simulating the law of large numbers and how it applies to standard deviation, as well. I wrote this code that works well but there is something that I am having a hard time understanding.

```
n <- 1000
dice.sd <- numeric(n)

sd(1:6) #1.870829

for (i in 1:n) {
  dice.sd[i] <- sd(sample(1:6, i, replace = TRUE))
}
plot(dice.sd)
abline(h=1.870829)
abline(h=1.7078)
```

As you can see, I made this loop to simulate LLN for standard deviations. According to the documentation, the sd() function uses n-1 for calculating the sample standard deviation, which should be about 1.87 for a die. However, when I run my simulation and graph the results, the standard deviation is converging to about 1.7078, which is the population standard deviation (using just n). Why is this the case? My loop originally was using the sample standard deviation, so why is it converging to the population standard deviation?

Comment: Close voters: this is _not_ a theory-related question

Comment: This isn't a really a programming question. This is a statistical question. The standard deviation will change based on the number of samples. If you run `sd(1:6)`, that's the standard deviation for observing the values 1,2,3,4,5,6. It does not really tell you about the theoretical distribution, Maybe this discussion will help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198025/what-are-the-variance-and-standard-deviation-for-a-standard-six-sided-die

Comment: @MrFlick OP has a bug in his code, which makes it a programming question

Comment: I don't believe your assumption about the convergence is correct. As n grows large then n-1=n, thus the sample standard deviation approaches the population sd. Thus the convergences is to the population standard deviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dice.sd[i] <- sd(sample(1:6, i, replace = TRUE))
```

This line creates a sample of size `i`, not a sample of size 6, which I assume is what you want. Your `i` goes up to 1000, which is large enough for the sample SD to be close to the population SD.

What you want is

```
dice.sd[i] <- sd(sample(1:6, 6, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: But this doesn't converge to anything. How would this have anything to do with the law of large numbers? Unless you start to take the cumulative mean of this vector. I don't know why you think this is a programming question. Seems like a clear misunderstanding of theoretical statistics.

Comment: Note the `abline(h=*)` in the question